# type of main function doesn't mean to my application

Tags: haskell, io, monads

As we know main function has type `IO ()`.
However, it is problem for me, because my program may return error.  It means that I am executing from main function something like that:

```
ErrorT String IO ()
```

Of course, at this moment I have problem with type errors.

What should I do ?

```
args <- getArgs
s <- readFile $ head args
myFoo s
```

Where `myFoo :: String -> ErrorT String IO ()`

Comment: BTW, `main` is not a function. It's an _action_. Functions are characterised by having arguments.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This sounds weird to me, is it in the language spec? The type signature of `main` suggests that it is a value. the "action" comes from the internal magic of the IO monad, right? Surely you wouldn't call `x :: Int; x = 5` an action?

Comment: @kai: of course it's also a value. Every“thing” in Haskell is a value, including functions and actions. Just, most values aren't functions, nor actions, indeed. The term _action_ isn't really well-defined, it's usually understood as a value of some type `M A` where `M` is a monad. `IO ()` does certainly qualify, `Int` certainly does not! It would be less clear-cut whether e.g. `[True]` should be considered an action.

Comment: Just as a note, the type of main is `IO a`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I would say these days many/most would say it's a value of some type `F A` where `F` is an applicative functor.

Comment: @DerekElkins, indeed it is, but IMO it's always best to fix it to either `IO ()`, `IO Void`, or polymorphic `IO a` (which is equivalent to `IO Void`). I choose one of the latter to indicate that the program can only terminate as the result of an exception.

Comment: Do not use `head` to inspect the argument list! That will give a very bad error message if there are no arguments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run it with `runErrorT`:

```
runErrorT :: ErrorT e m a -> m (Either e a)
```

Since `myFoo` returns a `ErrorT String IO ()` this will evaluate to an `IO (Either String ())` which you execute in `main` and match on the result:

```
args <- getArgs
s <- readFile $ head args
result <- runErrorT (myFoo s)
case result of
  Right _ -> putStrLn "ok!"
  Left(err) -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ err
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Lee's answer, you can then use [`exitFailure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-Exit.html#v:exitFailure) and [`exitSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-Exit.html#v:exitSuccess) from [`System.Exit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-Exit.html) to return an appropriate error code to the calling process:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad.Error
import System.Environment
import System.Exit

myFoo :: String -> ErrorT String IO ()
myFoo = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    s <- readFile $ head args
    result <- runErrorT (myFoo s)
    case result of
        Right _ -> do
            putStrLn "OK"
            exitSuccess
        Left (e) -> do
            putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ e
            exitFailure
```